# Definite integral from 0 to $\infty$ problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate the following function

$$\frac{\left(4 p^2+1\right) \left(e^{2 \pi  p} \sin ^2(t)+\cos ^2(t)\right)}{4 \left(e^{2 \pi  p}+1\right)}$$

from $p = 0$ to $p = \infty$.

Now suppose I set `t = 0` in the above integrand before integrating. Mathematica is able to produce an answer.

However, if I integrate the original integrand indefinitely? I will evaluate this expression at `t -> 0, p -> ∞` and `t -> 0, p -> 0``, then subtract the two, I should get the answer that I got in the step above. But in this case, Mathematica is not able to produce an answer, it tells me that the limit is indeterminate.

So what's going on? Definite integration works, but indefinite integration followed by taking the limits doesn't.

The Mathematica file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/my1j1kku1edf42x/Untitled-1.nb?dl=0).

Code:

```
Integrate[((1 + 4 p^2)(Cos[t]^2 + E^(2 p π)Sin[t]^2))/(4(1 + E^(2 p π))), {p, 0, ∞}]
```

Comment: The integral simply does not converge for $t\neq \pi n,n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral does not converge for some values of $t$.  Try plotting with $t=-1$:

```
t = -1;

Plot[
  Re[((1 + 4 p^2) (Cos[t]^2 + E^(2 p π) Sin[t]^2))/(4 (1 + E^(2 p π)))], 
  {p, 2, 10}]
```

so of course *Mathematica* cannot give a closed-form solution for arbitrary $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Quite the contrary to the accepted answer, Mathematica is able to integrate indefinitely, and give a sort of a solution. Of course, when one substitutes the limit of `p` as `Infinity`, one will get infinity back except when `Sin[t] == 0`.

But nonetheless, there's no problem with doing

```
Integrate[((1+4 p^2) (Cos[t]^2+E^(2 p π) Sin[t]^2))/(4 (1+E^(2 p π))) , p]
```

> ```
> (Pi^2*(p*(3 + 4*p^2)*Pi + Cos[2*t]*(p*(3 + 4*p^2)*Pi - 
>   3*(1 + 4*p^2)*Log[1 + E^(2*p*Pi)])) - 
>     12*p*Pi*Cos[2*t]*PolyLog[2, -E^(2*p*Pi)] + 
>       6*Cos[2*t]*PolyLog[3, -E^(2*p*Pi)])/(24*Pi^3)
> ```

Substituting

```
% /. t -> 0 // FullSimplify;
Limit[%, p -> Infinity] - (% /. p -> 0)
```

and getting the same answer as first setting `t` to 0 and doing the definite integral.

Comment: On the contrary, your result *agrees* with the comment under the OP, if we take $n=0 \in {\Bbb N}$, but I think ${\Bbb N}$ is a typo and should be ${\Bbb Z}$. -- Simpler: `Integrate[((1 + 4 p^2) (Cos[t]^2 + E^(2 p π) Sin[t]^2))/(4 (1 + E^(2 p π))) /. t -> 0, {p, 0, ∞}]`, which is the same as the result for any $t = \pi n$.

Comment: @MichaelE2 sorry, you're right, I'll correct that. Most likely, OP is using a later version of MMA that supports multivariate limits, because on 10.2 I can only take them in order. If I pick first `t->0` then `p->Infinity`, all is well (same as just replacing `t` with 0). So in a sense, I cannot reproduce the problem.